# preventing duplicate files in php

Tags: php

Trying to prevent a file from being duplicated in a users directory. This is what I have come up with,

```
$data = $connection->getMedia($fileid);
            /**
            * The test begins
            */
            $dir    = 'media/download/'.$username;
            $files1 = scandir($dir);
            foreach ($files1 as $i => $file) {
            if (md5($file) == md5($data)) {
                //statement
                echo "Duplicate entry detected.";                   
            }
            else {
                    file_put_contents($finalPath, $data);
            }
```

This, however, gives me an endless loop and I cant see what it is doing. So, can anyone give me a better idea.?

EDIT: the full code:

```
foreach ($accounts as $username => $password) {

        $connection= new Connection($username,$password);
        $fileList= $connection->getFiles();

        echo '<br><p>Last available files for '.$username.': <br>';
        if (!file_exists('media/download/'.$username)) {
                mkdir('media/download/'.$username, 0777, true);
            }

        for ($i=0;$i<7;$i++)
        {
            $fileID= $fileList[$i]->id;
            $data = $connection->getMedia($fileID);
            if (!strlen($data) < 1 ) {
                $recipient = $fileList[$i]->recipient;
                $finalPath = 'media/download/'.$username.'/to'.$recipient.'_id'.$fildID.rand(0,200).'.jpg';
                file_put_contents($finalPath, $data);
                echo  "<a href=".$finalPath."> <img src='".$finalPath."' height='100' width='100'> </a>";


            }




        }


    }
```

Comment: did you tried file_exists() http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php ?

Comment: Also, where is $finalPath defined ?  scandir only returns the filename, while you test the filename with your data ( which we're not sure what $data is )

Comment: We cannot say if this loop with run endless, since _you only posted the code of a part of the loop!_

Comment: That would be a very expensive operation even if it was working properly if there were a large number of files in the directory. If these are user files, why do you care if there are duplicates under different names?

Comment: I care for the purpose of limited storage. It is no longer looping, I will post updated code. The problem is that this code takes so long to operate in the first place, I need to make it go faster in general.

Comment: Storage is cheap, but if you REALLY want to prevent duplicates you could do this much better by performing hash on initial file write and storing those hashes in a database or other persistence layer for easy comparison of new files against existing hashes. No reason to re-hash every file in the directory with every file add.

Comment: You should also probably be using md5_file function for this.

Comment: @user2962806 "I need to make it go faster in general" this is a total different question: Consider making a candidate list by using fast operations for exclusion (filesize, md5 on an excerpt).

Comment: I am realizing that I can change the $finalPath to only the $fileId portion, and that part will NEVER change on the server, so it would effectively not make a duplicate, or is it overwriting them on the disk?